# Advanced Code Editor in Get and Transform

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, m

This seems like an odd question to ask on StackOverflow, but are there any options with the code editor when writing M code in Get & Transform? For me, it seems incredibly tedious to have to open the editor and click "Done" everytime I make a change. Is it possible to:

- Keep the editor open while saving changes?
- Any other editors that can be used that are more "full-screen" applications, such as Visual Studio Code?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I fully understand the question but the following resources might help:

- Here an editor is created using Notpad++ : https://ssbi-blog.de/blog/technical-topics-english/power-query-editor-using-notepad/
- You can run M queries in visual studio: https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2018/02/12/running-m-queries-in-visual-studio-with-the-power-query-sdk/